# Tinymce insert link autocomplete from db

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, tinymce, wysiwyg, tinymce-5

I use the tinymce editor. How can i insert a page link from my db with autocomplete..

I will type a few letters and tinymce editor will filter my database contents. I will choose one and it will automatically create the link.

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Ajax autocomple and tinymce plugins.
I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native [Autocompleter](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/autocompleter/) feature of TinyMCE should be sufficient.

You can put any HTML code into an autocompleter. E.g., this code can automatically add links to Amazon.com, Yahoo.com, and Google.com:

```js
const mySites = [
  { text: 'yahoo', name: 'Yahoo', value: '<a href = "https://yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a>' },
  { text: 'amazon', name: 'Amazon', value: '<a href = "https://amazon.com">Amazon!</a>' },
  { text: 'google', name: 'Google', value: '<a href = "https://google.com">Google!</a>' }
];
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea#autocompleter-cardmenuitem',
  height: 250,
  setup: (editor) => {
    const onAction = (autocompleteApi, rng, value) => {
      editor.selection.setRng(rng);
      editor.insertContent(value);
      autocompleteApi.hide();
    };

    const getMatchedChars = (pattern) => {
      return mySites.filter(char => char.text.indexOf(pattern) !== -1);
    };

    /**
     * An autocompleter that allows you to insert special characters.
     * Items are built using the CardMenuItem.
     */
    editor.ui.registry.addAutocompleter('mySites_cardmenuitems', {
      ch: ':',
      minChars: 1,
      columns: 1,
      highlightOn: ['char_name'],
      onAction: onAction,
      fetch: (pattern) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          const results = getMatchedChars(pattern).map(char => ({
            type: 'cardmenuitem',
            value: char.value,
            label: char.text,
            items: [
              {
                type: 'cardcontainer',
                direction: 'vertical',
                items: [
                  {
                    type: 'cardtext',
                    text: char.text,
                    name: 'char_name'
                  },
                  {
                    type: 'cardtext',
                    text: char.name
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }));
          resolve(results);
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/6/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="autocompleter-cardmenuitem">
  <p>Type <b>-</b> below and then keep typing to reduce further matches. For example, typing <b>:goo</b> should show the "Google" item in the menu. Pressing esc should close the autocomplete menu.</p>
  <p></p>
</textarea>
```

It won't run here, but you can test it [on CodePen](https://codepen.io/dmitrij-didenko/pen/NWOqgMW).

Comment: Thank you Dmitry it works and it's very functional. But i need to select the word and click the insert link button and then type the page name like your example :goo . Can i do like this?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you describe it in a step-by-step manner?